# Which should I use "I go swimming" or "I swim"?

Tags: verbs, present-tense, present-continuous

When to use 'I go swimming' and 'I swim'?
And,what are the differences between them?
Are they suitable to use.

Answer (score 1):

*To go swimming* is to spend some time swimming (in a swimming pool or the sea etc.) for pleasure or exercise. *To swim* is just to propel yourself through the water.

If you fall into water by accident and can swim to save yourself from drowning, you don't call it *going swimming.* On the other hand, if you go swimming regularly you might say "I swim at the nearby pool every day".

Answer (score 0):

A good answer to the question, "What do you do in summer when you are uncomfortably warm?" could be

> I go swimming.

In other words, swimming is what you do to cool off.

Interestingly, another good answer to the question, "What do you do in summer when you are uncomfortably warm" could be

> I swim.

Both answers are perfectly acceptable. Moreover, "I go swimming" and "I swim" say the same thing with slightly different wording. The verb in "I swim" is present tense; the verb in "I go swimming" is present participle. Here are a few sentences which illustrate how the two sentences can be used:

> When I get hot in summer, I swim. Sometimes I swim alone, and sometimes I go swimming with friends. When I am swimming in a pool, I like to have plenty of room all to myself. When the pool is crowded, I swim, but I am not comfortable swimming. That's because I keep bumping into people.
>
> In the public pool near my home, between 4 PM and 5 PM, the lifeguards install lane barriers so that people can swim laps without bumping into anyone. I swim in lane number 6 because I like swimming close to the edge of the pool.
>
> I go swimming in the ocean when my family goes on vacation to Myrtle Beach in South Carolina. I swim usually in the early morning when the beach is almost empty. I go swimming late in the day because the beach is not crowded then either.